# Regular expression validation for date

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In my asp.net application , i wants to enter date in the format DD-MM-YYYY where the entered date should be from today's date up to 6months..other wise it should shows an error message. What will be the validation expression for the control regular expression validator ?

Comment: Don't use a regular expression validator for dates.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my shot at a regular expression that tests it to be a valid date in the format you specified.

```
^[0-3]?\d-[0-1]?\d-\d{4}$
```

Testing that it's within a specific date range is beyond the capabilities of regular expressions.

For this you will need to write a custom validator.